# Модуль для работы с HID устройствами (флешками)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Мне нужно средствами python-а определить подключение устройства (флешки) к компьютеру, (А также вернуть букву диска.) как это можно реализовать? OS - Windows 10.

Comment: Попробуй посмотреть в сторону WMI. Вроде [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54484659/4928642) есть подписка на вставку флешек, надо только на питон переписать. Про букву диска не в курсе, но думаю там тоже может быть. Обрати внимание, что на флешке может быть несколько разделов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можна очень просто сделать с WMI. Получил букіу диска, а также серийний номер.

```py
import wmi

wmi = wmi.WMI()

for a in wmi.CIM_LogicalDisk():
    print(a)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо @Qwertiy